# Induced map from circle-to-plane inclusion map

Tags: differential-forms, vector-fields

I am reading “Introduction to Manifold” by L.W.Tu, and have trouble in understanding some facts given in Exercise 11.2 and Remark in Example 17.15 , which may be summarized as follows:

Suppose the inclusion map from $i :S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $i(\bar{x})=x$. The induced map $i_*: TS^1 \to T\mathbb{R}^2$ satisfies $i_*(\partial_{\bar{x}}) = \partial_x + (\partial\bar{y}/\partial\bar{x}) \partial_\bar{y}$, while for differential forms $i^*:T^*S^1\to T^* \mathbb{R}^2$ satisfies $i^* d\bar{x}=dx$.

I can see that these facts are true when calculated explicitly, but I cannot understand how should I depict them. That is, when considering the vector fields or differential forms on $S^1$, they are one-dimensional and I have seen they are written with the parameter $\theta$ or like that. I cannot explain why the vector fields and differential forms should written with the induced Cartetian coordinates. How can I visualize such vector fields and differential forms on $S^1$?

Could someone help me?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A chart of $S^1$ can be $\phi^{-1}$ where

$\phi: (0,2\pi)\to S^1$

$\phi(\theta):=(cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$

Now you say that

$i_*(\partial_\theta)=a\partial_x+b\partial_y$

where $(x,y)$ are the coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^2$

We want calculate $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ but

$a=i_*(\partial_\theta)(x)=\partial_\theta(x\circ (i\circ (\phi^{-1})^{-1}))=\partial_\theta(cos(\theta))=-sin(\theta)$

while

$b=i_*(\partial_\theta)(y)=\partial_\theta(y\circ (\phi^{-1})^{-1}))=\partial_\theta(sin(\theta))=cos(\theta)$

So

$i_*(\partial_\theta)=-sin(\theta)\partial_x+cos(\theta)\partial_y$

You can observe that $i_*$ is an injective linear map because there is not $\theta$ such that $-sin(\theta)=cos(\theta)=0$ so $i$ is an immersion map.

It is not correct to write $i^*:T^*S^1\to T^*\mathbb{R}^2$ because the differentital of a smooth map is  a contro-variant functor, so you must have

$i^*:T^*\mathbb{R}^2\to T^*S^1$.

Now

$i^*(dx)=\alpha d\theta$
and $i^*(dy)=\beta d\theta$

for some $\alpha,\beta$, so

$\alpha=i^*(dx)(\partial_\theta)=dx(i_*(\partial_\theta))=dx(a\partial_x+b\partial_y)=a=-sin(\theta)$ while

$\beta= i^*(dy)(\partial_\theta)=dy(i_*(\partial_\theta))=dx(a\partial_x+b\partial_y)=b=cos(\theta)$

Then

$i^*(dx)=-sin(\theta) d\theta$
and $i^*(dy)=cos(\theta) d\theta$

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind reply, Federico Fallucca.
I see how vector fields on $S^1$ are reparameterized from the one-dimensional to the Cartetian coordinates. It was a great help for me.
What I cannot still grasp is why $\bar{x}$ and $x$ in the two coordinates change the coefficients of the same vector: like you suggested, if the one-dimensional vector field is included in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and projected to the Cartetian coordinates like $-sin$ and $cos$ you wrote, why the coefficients change when written in $\bar{x}$ and $x$? 
Sorry for my poor writing. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand you question, can you write it in a different version?

Comment: Sorry for confusing you with my poor writing.
In my understanding, $\partial_{\bar{x}}$ is itself projected vector from $\partial_\theta$, and thus it is a vector on the Cartetian coordinate system. So, I cannot see the intuitive understanding of the difference between $\partial_x$ And $\partial_{\bar{x}}$. 
Thank you for your continuous replies.

Comment: When you think to a tangent vector \partial_\var{x} of S^1 you must think to an abstract circle and a vector tangent to the circle, but if you want represent that circle in Cartesian coordinate you must think the circle in the space R^2 in which in each point the tangent space is R^2, so that vector will be a combination of two elements of bases of the tangent space of R^2.

Comment: Thank you Federico. Sorry for my late reply. 
I now see that the difference between the vector spaces of $S^1$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$, where the number of base vectors are one and two and thus I must consider the combination of base vectors in the latter.

Comment: I have updated in my mind what does not sound right to me. In the textbook(sorry that I cannot share the figure here) the pictorial explanation says that $\partial_{\bar{x}}$ is attached along the the circle as it is parallel to $\partial_{\theta}$, while $\partial_{x}$ is along the x-axis of the Cartetian coordinates. This seems strange to me, because $\partial_{\bar{x}}$ must also be parallel to the x-axis as well.  How should I interpret this?

Comment: Thank you also for your reply about the differential forms. It gave me a great insight! I now understand that $i^*$ should acts reversely, since it is a contravariant fancot as you suggested.